Dilating baked (BW) texture
I have an object with black/white (binary) baked textures, and I want to dilate the white regions by some amount. The islands on the uv map are offset by a margin. I have tried a few things, without any success.
A simple example would be a black cube with a white dot in the middle of one face. I want the dot to spreas in all directions and eventually expand over the edges to other faces. In my actual case, there can be multiple white irregular regions.
I have understood from previous questions that it is difficult to do this in shader nodes, especially since I dont want to modify my geometry or subdivide.
Doing this in 2d using the baked texture and morphological dilation is one option, but its not trivial because of disconnected UV Islands. I would somehow need to dilate over UV boundaries, using information about joint edges. I feel there should exist a  algorithm for this, but I cannot find anything online. In a way this option is preferable as it would offer the most control.
Another option would be to use the spread feature in dynamic paint. This would achieve the desired outcome, but the problem is that I dont really have a brush. It does not seem to be possible to assign my baked texture as an initial (wet) paint and let it be affected by the spread effect available under the canvas options.
I have also seen people achive spreading or dripping effects with geometry nodes, but I dont know how to use my texture as initial condition.
